# How to achieve call masking?

Tags: java, android, call, mask

I am developing an android application (Tele Calling).

1. I want to hide mobile number while making the call.
2. Is it possible?
3. is it legal?

**For example:**

`if the number is 1230129012. Then it will be displayed as 00000001 while calling.`

Comment: I think you'll be at the whim of whatever the phone app's behavior is (assuming you are doing this via an `Intent`).

Comment: If we passed the mobile number through intent System app only have the control for making calls, then how can we hide the mobile number